# how to clear the value after refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

Need help how to clear the text box value after refreshing the page? actually I am using search text box after submit a form still displayed the value inside text box it is working fine, but I want when I refresh the page clear the value.
this is my code,

```
<div class="form-group" style='float:left;margin-right:10px;' id="normal_search">
     {!! Form::text('search', '', array('id'=>'yearly_search_id','class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('main.search').' '.trans('main.customer.title') )) !!}
</div>
```

using local storage,

```
localStorage.yearlySearchFilter = $("#yearly_search_id").val();
$("#yearly_search_id").val(localStorage.yearlySearchFilter);
```

Comment: stop populating value to `#yearly_search_id` using `localStorage`.

Comment: only when  I page refresh $("#yearly_search_id").val(" ") need empty  text box how ?

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript you can do:

```
function init() {
document.getElementById("normal_search").value = "";
}
window.onload = init;
```

Or in jQuery simply do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#normal_search").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can did in this way (to clear the all Form Input fields).

> As you use localstorage.Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       localStorage.clear();
       //localStorage.removeItem("name of localStorage variable you want to remove");
});
```

Comment: how about select ?

Comment: by find it from the current form and reset its index. to 0(zero)

Comment: Actually my question is when i search the text then enter form is submitted then the search values display inside search box this is working fine but

Comment: when I refresh the page not able to clear the search box inside search value that is my question

Comment: Yes, I got your question properly, this script runs after your AJAX call for search is finish successfully. this will clear your all filed values before page refresh.

Comment: only when I refresh the page  $("#yearly_search_id").val(" ") need empty text box how ?

Comment: it is a search text box for list page

Comment: so when I refresh the page need search text box values empty

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
localStorage.yearlySearchFilter = $("#yearly_search_id").val();
$("#yearly_search_id").val(localStorage.yearlySearchFilter);
```

Use this:

```
localStorage.yearlySearchFilter = $("#yearly_search_id").val();
```

You will not find any value in search box on page load.

Comment: FYI. `localStorage` remains same even after page reload. So only first time it will be filled then it will have previous value.

Comment: Yes manoj i have try the problem is when i click refresh button page is refreshed but value still displayed

Comment: Can you share the "refresh button" click event?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me You can clear the localStorage right after you get the value from it

Comment: when I page refresh that time clear the localStorage  value how ?

Comment: Use localStorage.clear() if you want to clear it completely or use localStorage.removeItem(key) if you want to remove a specific item("yearlySearchFilter" in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can reset form fields with this piece of code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').find("input[type='text'],textarea").val("");
   });
```